# nginx Virtual host, http server and tcp port forward

Tags: nginx, tcp, proxy

I have an nginx server which serves a static html page on port for `example.com` virtual host.

There are two more servers running on `localhost:50001` and `localhost:50002`,

I want to forward all requests to `example.com` in following way

```
example.com          --->      /var/www/servers/example.com/
example.com:50001    --->      localhost:50001
example.com:50002    --->      localhost:50002
```

How can I achieve this?

I am able to achieve the first one, and started listening on `50001` and `50002`

Here is the config

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        listen 50001;
        listen [::]:50001;

        listen 50002;
        listen [::]:50002;

        root /var/www/servers/example.com/;

        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name example.com;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }


         location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;

                fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;

        }

        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think a reverse proxy is what you need. Following the rules of [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-14-04), it's pretty simple.

First, delete those lines from the main config, (it also works on the default config, you just have to separate ports creating new `server {}` blocks to each one).

```
listen 50001;
listen [::]:50001;

listen 50002;
listen [::]:50002;
```

The thing is create two more Server Blocks config, so we have the `/etc/nginx/sites-available/exampleat50001.com`

```
server {
  listen 50001;

  server_name example.com;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:50001;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }
}
```

The same with the app at port 50002. The last thing is restart the nginx server.

`# systemctl restart nginx.service`

Hope it works for you :)